# jquery addclass to field if field equals certain value

Tags: jquery, onchange, jquery-chosen

im trying to add a class on the fly to an input, if the selected value equals a certain value.

```
$("#schedule_event").chosen().change( function() {
        $('#1').slideUp();
        $('#2').slideUp();
        $('#3').slideUp();
        $('#' + $(this).val()).slideDown();
        if($(this).val == 1) {
            $("#schedule_opponent_id").addClass("required");
        }
```

or if there is a way of validating this through RoR validators would be great
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the right approach but `val` is a method not a property (therefore you need to add `()` to invoke it).  You should probably also remove the class if your criteria isn't met.  That way if the field is changed to an option with a value other than `1` the `#schedule_opponent_id` field will no longer have the `required` class.

```
$("#schedule_event").chosen().change( function() {
    $('#1').slideUp();
    $('#2').slideUp();
    $('#3').slideUp();
    $('#' + $(this).val()).slideDown();
    if($(this).val() == 1) {
        $("#schedule_opponent_id").addClass("required");
    } else {
        $("#schedule_opponent_id").removeClass("required");
    }
```

Comment: and im doing the best method of the slide up/down, it seems a bit hack to me

Comment: that works but ive just realised it doesnt stop my form form being submitted, so i might need to validate on the server side of things rather than the client

Comment: @Paul'Whippet'McGuane You should always do server side validation regardless of whether you do it on the client side.  If you want to stop the form from being submitted you can attach an `onsubmit` event to the form in question and return false if you want to prevent submission.  `$('form').on('submit', function() { return true/false; });`